# Apply css properties depending on which browser is used

Tags: css

I want to apply different css properties depending on which browser is used, 
If browser is Firefox version 4.0 use this code:

```
.lastnews-Col {
    height: 360px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
```

If browser is not Firefox version 4.0 apply this css property :

```
.lastnews-Col {
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Ideally, you should write markup/css that does not require browser-based variations.  I'd re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: Firefox 4 is as good a browser as Chrome 11 and Opera 11 and such. Why make the difference? There are several CSS hacks to distinguish IE6 and IE7, which should be enough. I very much agree with Kon.

Comment: Agree with these comments, if you feel the need to hack FF4, chances are that you're making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Question was how to select FF4, not about validity of code.

Comment: Seler's answer below is correct, but I would seriously consider what Kon is saying. If you are using a good CSS reset, all of the modern browsers should render near exactly the same with few exceptions. Old IE specific CSS was to compensate for poor standards compliance which should not be an issue with new browsers.

Comment: -1 because targeting browsers is not something to be recommended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use firefox 4 specific selector: -moz-any()
http://jsfiddle.net/seler/yuKxW/1/

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about this. This is FF4 specific?

Comment: @Wesley, sure it is. Test it. (I use Spoon to test different versions of browsers)

Comment: I only have FF4 installed so I can't test. Spoon? Anyways, great solution to use `-moz` properties. (+1 implied)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [CSS Browser Selector/](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/).

Comment: Javascript for browser sniffing for CSS properties? Now that's a real bad idea.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but this method don't support FireFox 4.0